# MSSQL query to get available systems %

Tags: sql-server

| Hostname | Role | OS | Start of Downtime | End of Downtime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Test01 | Server | 2019 | 2022-08-01 01:00:15 | 2022-08-07 01:00:15 |
| Test02 | Server | 2019 | 2022-08-01 02:00:15 | 2022-08-03 01:00:15 |
| Test03 | Server | 2019 | 2022-08-04 01:00:15 | 2022-08-05 01:00:15 |
| Test04 | Server | 2019 | 2022-08-05 01:00:15 | 2022-08-06 01:00:15 |
| Test05 | Server | 2019 | 2022-08-05 01:00:15 | 2022-08-06 02:00:15 |

I have the above table and want to report that for any moment in time at least 90% of systems don't have downtime.
In reality there are more than 5 systems.

Can anyone assist in this?

Output could be:

| Date | Systems with downtime | Duration in seconds | Start of Downtime | End of Downtime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-01 | 2 | xxxx | 2022-08-01 01:00:15 | 2022-08-01 23:59:59 |
| 2022-08-02 | 2 | xxxx | 2022-08-02 00:00:00 | 2022-08-02 23:59:59 |
| 2022-08-03 | 2 | xxxx | 2022-08-03 00:00:00 | 2022-08-03 01:00:15 |
| 2022-08-03 | 1 | xxx | 2022-08-03 00:00:00 | 2022-08-03 23:59:59 |
| 2022-08-04 | 1 | xxx | 2022-08-04 00:00:00 | 2022-08-04 01:00:14 |
| 2022-08-04 | 2 | xxx | 2022-08-04 01:00:05 | 2022-08-04 23:59:59 |

Comment: Show us your code.  What have you tried, and what about that is not working?

Comment: here is a hint - you will need to use `DATEDIFF()`, `COUNT()` and `GROUP BY`